# Callback doesn't edit value

Tags: typescript

I try to get a result from a series of callback. The problem is that no result at all could be return.

Here is the code I'm trying to get around :

Main function :

```
let userldap:userLDAP = {controls:[],objectClass:[],dn:"",sn:"",givenName:"",mail:"",uid:"",cn:"",userPassword:""};
let res:ldapRes = {err:"",info:"",user:userldap};

this.ldap.authentication(credentials,res);
```

So, basicly, I'm just trying to edit values in the res object.

Service :

```
  public authentication(
    credentials: Credentials,
    res:ldapRes,
  ):void {
    this.ldap.authenticate(credentials.username, credentials.password,function(err:string,user:any,info:string) {
          res.err = err;
          res.info=info;
          res.user=user;
      });
  }
```

It's really a pretty basic usage. Despite this, the callback in the authenticate function seems to not edit the res object.

I tryed many things like global context or anything, but still the callback in authenticate function seems to just do his work, than vanish from the very universe. Even if the object is changed in, it just reset to its old value.

So if anyone have a clue about what I'm messing up (because it's a basic of code, a problem of variable range of definition, I know it, but can't find solution), I'll be glad to hear it :) .

Thanks.

EDIT : As suggested, and as already tryed, an await on the callback inside the auth function doesn't solve the matter :

```
public async authentication(credentials : Credentials, res: ldapRes):Promise<ldapRes>{
    //console.log(res);
    await this.ldap.authenticate(credentials.username, credentials.password, function(err:string,user:any,info:string) {
      res.err = err; res.info=info; res.user = user;
      console.log("Callback from inside auth function :");
      console.log(res);
    });
    console.log("Callback from outside auth function :");
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  }
```

In this case, the log from inside work like a charm, and the one on the outside still display a reseted version of res (no value).

Comment: Are you attempting to use the changed values too soon? With async code, it's common to depend on `res` changing before it has. The code that depends on the change should be part of / called from the callback function.

Comment: @Fenton Yeah, I know this, the problem is that my main function have to send back a user. So, I can't make a return from an other callback, it must be this function (framework constraint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out what was the way to do it. The problem was our misconception about the Promise principe in Typescript. The fact is that you can return a promise in the function, not only the User object.

Main function :

```
async verifyCredentials(credentials: Credentials): Promise<User> {
    let proms = new Promise<User>(function(resolve,reject){
      ldap.authentication(credentials).then(val => {
        let foundUser : User = new User();
        foundUser.email = val.user.mail;
        foundUser.firstName = val.user.givenName;
        foundUser.lastName = val.user.sn;
        foundUser.id = val.user.uid;
        resolve(foundUser);
      }) 
    })
    return proms;
  }
```

LDAP function :

```
public async authentication(
    credentials: Credentials,
  ){
    return new Promise<ldapRes>(function(resolve, reject){

      ldap.authenticate(credentials.username, credentials.password,function(err:string,user:any,info:string) {
        resolve({err,user,info});
      });

    });

  }
```